# VirtualHost configuration (rewrite) not working when using SSL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ssl, https, virtualhost

I am using the following directives to configure my VirtualHost in Plesk:

```
[vhost.conf]

ServerName www.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !^.+\.(css)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.+js
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1/

<Directory /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    php_admin_flag safe_mode Off
</Directory>
```

This worked fine in every case, until i added an SSL certificate and accessed the server through `https`. Now the rewrites were no longer working, when calling the site through SSL.

So i figured that the configuration loaded for the other protocol (`https`) must differ from the one that is loaded in the case of `http`.

I then found out that Plesk uses two separate config files for both protocols. I copied `vhost.conf` to `vhost_ssl.conf`. Now the site loaded fine over `https` and the rewrites were working fine.

But now the rewrites were no longer working when accessing the site through `http`.

Seems like the cat is biting its tail, i am running in circles and out of options.

Unfortunately i lack the experience in configuring apache. I do assume that somehow my two sets of rules are causing a problem, but after all they are included into two different `<VirtualHost>` directives.

Perhaps someone knows what is going on here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you how to fix it but I can tell you how to start.

Look carefully at the access and error logs.  Read about this here:  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html

There are a bunch of tools to help you with this debugging described there and in linked pages.